# Restrict number of applications in a workspace in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Is there a way in oracle apex 5 to limit number of applications creation in a workspace?

Comment: No, but you can effectively limit the number of applications created on the whole database instance by setting Instance Settings, Application ID Range.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no such a *property* in Apex Administration (at least, I don't know of any).

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/admin.32/e13371/wrkspc.htm#AEADM101) says

> In an Oracle Application Express development environment, users log in
>   to a shared work area called a workspace. A workspace is a virtual
>   private database that enables multiple users to work within the same
>   Oracle Application Express installation while keeping their objects,
>   data and applications private. This flexible architecture enables a
>   single database instance to manage **thousands of applications**.

I read it as: "See? No limits!".

[Apex Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/limits.htm#HTMDB28629) contain *Development Environment* and *Component* limits, but none of them says anything about number of applications per workspace.

Therefore, I'd say that no, you can't do that.

**However**, this is Oracle. Apex is bunch of tables, packages etc., all stored in the database. It means that there should be a table that contains those information - I imagine it as a master-detail relationship, WORKSPACE being a master and APPLICATIONS a detail table. I have no idea how are those tables called, but - if you have your own Apex installation, you might try to dig deeply into it, find those tables and create a **trigger** which would prevent more than (for example) 3 applications per workspace.

Would it affect something else, perhaps even broke Apex? I have no idea, but - if you ever try it, remember to let us know the outcome.

On the other hand, someone else might know better and will be able to assist you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, from your answers it seems very clear that it cannot be done without any deep digging, i`ll try to look for the tables and check if something can be done , will share if i find something working , thank you